# How to get the caller object name in the catch block

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to get the object name of a method in the catch block. i want to log the hierarchy of the objects that contain exception.

```
var facades = function() {
    return {
            facade1: {
                method1: function() {
                    throw new Error('this is a fake exception');
                }
            }
        }

}();

try {
    facades.facade1.method1()
} catch(e) {
    //i want to log facades and facade1 here
}
```

how can i log the "facades" and "facade1" strings?
(or how should i change my structure to do this)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that.

Comment: yes i know that. i want to log the reason of the exception. consider that there are a lot of facades in my code. i want to know which one caused the exception

Comment: I agree with @Barmar, there isn't an automated way of doing that.  You would have to log it by hand.

Comment: You can get `facade1` and `method1`. There is no way to access `facade`.

Comment: set a global variable that changes whenever you enter the body of one of these methods and then you can log that in your catch